# What is an elementary yet important application of matrix in finance?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, big-list, finance, applications

What is an elementary yet important application of matrix in finance?

I have difficulty to read anything intermediate/advanced associated with this topics, hopefully I can find something interesting regard on this topic.

Comment: So I undid the -1 vote. I though this to be a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covariance matrices, SVD decomposition. etc...